# Mapping different HTTP JSON response using Jackson

Tags: json, spring, kotlin, jackson, okhttp

I'm making a web server using Spring(Kotlin), and trying to map JSON response using Jackson.
I need to send a request to other API server, so I decided to use OkHttp to send request.
But, there is a problem that If the other API server responds with error like 4XX, Jackson couldn't map response because the response has different JSON structure.

Here's the code:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
fun test(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody requestJSON: RequestJSON): Message {
    val JSON: MediaType = "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaType()
    val mapper = ObjectMapper()
    val requestJSONString: String = mapper.writeValueAsString(requestJSON)

    val client = OkHttpClient()
    val body: RequestBody = requestJSONString.toRequestBody(JSON)
    val request: Request = Request.Builder()
        .header("clientid", "blahblah")
        .header("secret", "blahblah")
        .url("blahblah")
        .post(body)
        .build()
    val response: Response = client.newCall(request).execute()
    return mapper.readValue(response.body?.string(), Message::class.java)
}
```

The class "Message" has a structure like this:

```
class Message {
    var message = NestedMessage()

    class NestedMessage {
        @JsonProperty("@type")
        var type: String? = null

        @JsonProperty("@service")
        var service: String? = null

        @JsonProperty("@version")
        var version: String? = null

        @JsonProperty("result")
        var resultObject = Result()

        class Result {
            var srcLangType: String? = null
            var tarLangType: String? = null
            var translatedText: String? = null
            var engineType: String? = null
            var pivot: String? = null
            var dict: String? = null
            var tarDict: String? = null
        }
    }
}
```

And, an error of other API server has a structure like this:

```
class Error {
    var errCode: String? = null
    var errMessage: String? = null
}
```

How can I map different JSON response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create two different Struct for the northbound API and the southbound API.

For the southbound API, add `errCode` and `errMessage` to SouthBoundMessage. Or check the HTTP status code if you can, then use a different Jackson mapper for Error Message.

Then convert SouthBoundMessage to NorthBoundMessage, which is your business logic.

Return NorthBoundMessage and corresponding HTTP code for northbound API consumers.